# Как проксировать куки в nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy

Есть вот такая конфигурация, но куки почему-то не прокисруются.

```
    location / {
    error_log off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cookie_domain www.$host $host;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }
```

Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так: `proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";` Правда здесь принудительно указаны `HttpOnly` и `SameSite strict`.

Но если подойдёт, вы можете поправить под себя. И мое мнение что директива `proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;` лишняя.